# Is there a better way to loop through an array of strings like these?

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, keyword

I don't know if there is a better way to loop through the sentences and check if the included keywords are there and the excluded keywords aren't.

```js
if (match !== true) {
    sentences.forEach(sentence => {
        for (let i = 0; i < include.length; i++) {
            for (let e = 0; e < exclude.length; e++) {
                if (
                    sentence.includes(include[i]) &&
                    !sentence.includes(exclude[e])
                ) {
                    console.log(`Matched the word "${include[i]}" in the sentence "${sentence}"`);
                    match = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    match = false;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This is the output of the code above:

```
Matched the word "father" in the sentence "Man, I am not your father".
Matched the word "son" in the sentence "You are my son!"
No match!
Loop ended.
```

Will a `filter` method work?

Comment: You don't need to nest your include and exclude loops--you'll end up looping through your exclude array once for every single include word. You can loop through the exclude array first and check if the sentence contains any of those words and if so, continue to the next sentence. Then a second loop after the first can check if any of the include words are present.

Comment: `sentences.filter(sentence => include.some(word => sentence.includes(word)) && !exclude.some(word => sentence.includes(word)))` (untested)